# GStreamer: Plug-ins with dependencies that will NOT be built

Tags: linux, webrtc, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I am trying to install the WebRTC plugin for gstreamer from gst-plugins-bad. https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/src/gst-plugins-bad/

When running the configure Script, the following message comes:
**configure: Plug-ins with dependencies that will NOT be built:**
followed by a list of plugins. When I install using make, these plugins are not installed. Is there some dependencies that i need to install?

Logs from configure script can be found at: https://justpaste.it/4w2kl

Comment: Each plugin has its own 3rd party dependencies. If they are found on your system the plugins are build. If not, they are not. The list of dependencies and their own dependencies are extremely long. If you really want to build everything I recommend looking at https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/building-from-source-using-cerbero.html

Comment: This is to build GStreamer from scratch. Isn't there a list of dependencies which i can download and then the script will install WebRTC plugin?

Comment: WebRTC in particular I don't know. Easiest is always to use prebuild binaries and packages.

Comment: This may be a silly question but can't we get the list of dependencies from the configure file? It checks the dependencies right?

Answer (score 0):

Open `configure.ac` and search for `webrtc` there.

There are two plugins: `webrtc` and `webrtcdsp`. The second one is for the audio processing involved: echo cancellation, noise suppression, etc. Read more about it [here](http://ndufresne.ca/2016/06/gstreamer-echo-canceller/).

I'm looking at the version 1.16, in that file I can find that `webrtc` requires `nice >= 0.1.14`, this is [libnice](https://nice.freedesktop.org/). And for `webrtcdsp` there is `Note: We test for a specific version as there is no API stability` and the requirement is `webrtc-audio-processing >= 0.2` and `< 0.4`, [here](https://freedesktop.org/software/pulseaudio/webrtc-audio-processing/) is the lib. So you can check whether your package manager has the needed versions or build them yourself. `webrtcdsp` also needs `gnustl` on `android` and tests for `vector` C++ header. But, again, this is for the specific version, you are supposed to check the file yourself.

If you are going to build some dependencies by yourself, you may find useful the [recipes](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/cerbero/tree/master/recipes) that GStreamer uses during their own Cerbero build, especially useful are the applied patches.